# Instead of ID column, how to use other DB column for my route

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::get('subscribers/{subscriber}', 'SubscriberController@show');
```

In my controller's `show` method, I want it to use the `email` as a lookup to my table instead of the default `id`. Is this possible?

```
public function show(Subscriber $subscriber)
{
    // I need this to do like
    // $subscriber = Subscriber::findOrFail(<email>);
    //
    // instead of the default
    // $subscriber = Subscriber::finaOrFail(<id>);

    return $subscriber;
}
```

I tried to look for an answer here in StackOverflow but my limited knowledge about Laravel does not seem to allow me to use the right keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following method to your `Subscriber` Model.

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'email';
}
```

You can read more about [Route Model Binding in the Laravel Documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)